# How to call a wcf service/Web services using Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, wcf-data-services, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I surfed a lot about this issue, but unable to find the solution for this. Here the problem is, I want to connect to a wcf using Apache Cordova and Visual Studio.
So if any one found a proper working solution please post the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can do this in cordova wit JQuery.
See
[Calling Cross Domain WCF service using Jquery/Javascript](https://dzone.com/articles/calling-cross-domain-wcf)

For this the WCF-Services must have the Attribute

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

and the Service-Methods to get Data must decorated with

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

But first, I'm going to checkout the code provided in this 
[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235426/cordova-phonegap-simple-jquery-call) and post the result here.

Comment: I think that links only shows how to connect to Auth0 using either Cordova or WCF; but it does not show how to connect a Cordova client to a WCF service.

Comment: @JulienLebot You are right, the link was missleading, got my first downvote. I deleted the link and provided a new one. I hope someone find out and post a more detailed answer, as I would do, if I get more Time for this toppic.

Comment: upvoted for fixed link. In the page linked you can find a blog post which links to this article on code project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery quite old but should do.